# How to "pack" a variable amount of outputs from a function in Lua?

Tags: lua, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking

I have a function in Lua that gives a variable number of outputs. How can I get all its outputs, regardless of how many outputs it has?

```lua
function my_function()
    -- whatever
end

outputs_list = my_function()
```

The above example doesn't work because `outputs_list` gets only the first output of the function, and all the others are discarded.
I want `outputs_list` to contain all the outputs of the function so I can retrieve them later.

I think this is equivalent in python to doing `*outputs_list = my_function()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can capture the values into a *table*

```lua
local t = { foo() }
```

but it may not be a [*sequence*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7) if the function returns *nil* values that create holes in the list.

[`select`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-select) may be used to choose where to begin capturing return values.

```lua
-- capture the second return value and onwards
local t = { select(2, foo()) }
```

---

In Lua 5.2+, you also have access to [`table.pack(...)`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.pack), which

> Returns a new table with all arguments stored into keys 1, 2, etc. and with a field "n" with the total number of arguments. Note that the resulting table may not be a sequence, if some arguments are nil.

The caveat about the resulting table not being a sequence means that looping over all the returned values may require a numeric `for`, instead of a generic one using `ipairs`.

```lua
local function foo()
    return 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
end

local results = table.pack(foo())

for i = 1, results.n do
    print(results[i])
end
```

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

The opposite function is [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack).

---

In Lua 5.1, you can polyfill `table.pack` as

```lua
table.pack = function (...)
    local t = { ... }
    t.n = select('#', ...)
    return t
end
```

Comment: This sounds nice, is there a way to pack only, say all outputs except the first one ? Like in python, `output_1, *other_outputs = my_function` ?

Comment: @MateoVial Added a note about `select`.

Comment: Excellent answer. A couple tiny things I'd like to add: 1. The polyfill can be written as a single expression using `{n = select('#', ...), ...}` (but not the other way around, otherwise the vararg is truncated); 2. In Lua 5.1, `table.unpack` needs to be polyfilled as `unpack(t, 1, t.n)`; 3. There are other ways to store varargs (such as using a coroutine) - you can find them [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/VarargTheSecondClassCitizen) - but using a table is generally regarded as the best one.

Comment: @Luatic Does Lua 5.2+'s [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack) fundamentally differ from Lua 5.1's [`unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) (i.e., does the former consider an `.n` member)? The manual descriptions are very similar. The source code looks nearly identical ([5.1](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_unpack), [5.2](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltablib.c.html#unpack)), as well. Otherwise, your suggested polyfill is more like an applicable use case for all versions (for when *t* is not a sequence) no?

Comment: @Oka Yeah, my bad, it's not a polyfill; rather it's how to properly unpack a vararg if it's not a sequence - apparently `unpack` was just moved to the `table` scope with its functionality left unchanged despite the introduction of `table.pack`.

Comment: One interesting thing to note though, unlike the following versions, Lua 5.2's `table.unpack` (table library in general) does not invoke getter (and setter) metamethods (it *does* invoke `__len` with no third argument, like the following versions). This was [changed in Lua 5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.2).